# Problems with Makefile and compiling a cpp file marks error in a function declared in other file

Tags: c++

I have problems with my Makefile.
I used the following structure to generate the .o files of each cpp file, but does not work (using c works without problems, I cant find what is the problem)

```
%.o : %.cpp %.h
    g++ -c -Wall $< -o $@
```

And the error while compiling is a function is declared in a separated h and cpp file and added to the main file. But when I try to generate de .o file of main.cpp marks error in the function.

The command I used to compile the main.cpp -> *g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o*

The error that gives me is:

**main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)**’:
main.cpp:9:9: error: ‘number’ was not declared in this scope9 | number();**

This is the compiler that I used for it:
g++ (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
Linux 5.15.0-40-generic

Please, anyone could explain me if I'm doing wrong of something is left

```
/*main.cpp*/
#include <iostream>
#include "numb.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout<<"Run"<<endl;
    number();
    cout<<"end Run"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
/*end main.cpp*/

/*numb.cpp*/
#include <iostream>
#include "numb.h"

using namespace std;

int number()
{
    cout<<"Function"<<endl;

    return 117;
}
/*end numb.cpp*/

/*numb.h*/
#include <iostream>
#define NUMB_H
#ifndef NUMB_H

int number();

#endif
/*end numb.h*/
```

Comment: `#define NUMB_H
#ifndef NUMB_H` What happened here?

Comment: You have those #define #ifndef in the wrong order.

Comment: And #include <iostream> should be `#ifndef ... #define ... #include ...`

Comment: Having `%.h` as a target dependency is kinda pointless. You need all included headers in there, but you shouldn't write them manually: compile with `-MMD -MP`, then `-include` the resulting .d files.

Comment: If you are not using iostream in the numb.h header don't include it. This will not make a difference when your code is small but when its hundreds of thousands of lines in hundreds of cpp files and takes tens of minutes to build you will be happy that you included only the files you need.

Comment: I suspect that you are not sure what `#define NUMB_H` does.  If you learn what that means, you will understand that the line immediately following it is illogical.

Comment: Thanks for the advise with the include when is already declared by other file
And is correct I have in wrong place the #define NUMB_H and the #ifndef NUMB_H
Should be
#ifndef NUMB_H
#define NUMB_H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the header guard in the wrong order.
Instead of:

```
#define NUMB_H
#ifndef NUMB_H
```

It is supposed to be:

```
#ifndef NUMB_H
#define NUMB_H
```

Comment: Thanks you were right. Also this solve my problem with the make file

Answer (score 0):

When compiling specify both CPP files, because `#include` fixes compile errors, but does not fix linker errors

```
g++ -c main.cpp numb.cpp ...
```

As a rule, in header files nothing have to be outside the `#define` guards:

```cpp
/*numb.h*/
#define NUMB_H
#ifndef NUMB_H
#include <iostream>
```